# Progress bar in Ruby/Green Shoes

Tags: ruby, progress-bar, shoes

I am trying to get a progress bar to work in Ruby with Green Shoes. My problem is that the progress of the bar that I am creating isn't showing. The state of my bar is either empty at the begining and during the execution of the code or full at the end.

Here is the structure of my code:

```
Shoes.app do
  button("Run") do
    progress_bar = progress left: 10, top: 10, width: 235
    backup_exe = File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/backuplist.txt","r+")
    count = 0
    File.open(backup_exe) {|f| count = f.read.count("\n")}
    counter = 0
    count = count.to_f
    puts count
    animate do |counter|                
    backup_exe.each  do |line|
        counter=counter+1
        progress_bar.fraction = ((counter/count)*10).round / 10.0
        puts progress_bar.fraction
            sleep(2)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What’s the output of `puts count`?

Comment: `width: 235` sounds weird for me then. It looks like you muddle `width` which is the “bar range” and it’s horizontal size. Try `progress_bar = progress width: 1.0`.

Comment: Hum, I see... But it's still not doing it. The bar is either full or empty!

Comment: You definitely calculate `fraction` erroneously. Try to print out all the values and make sure they are `∈[0,1]`. Unfortunately I can’t reproduce the case because of lack of dev env.

Comment: Nope, I checked and I am in the interval.

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with the animate loop. But I can't find doc on it. Do you know where I could find some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I need to put values that populates fraction in a new Thread.
Thanks mudasobwa for your input!